# Grub only works after viewing bios first

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I have my PC set to dual boot with Ubuntu 18 and Windows 10 but, when I boot my PC, grub doesn't start properly (it displays the grub command line instead of loading the options to start Ubuntu or Windows).

After it happened for the first time, I was playing around with the bios in the boot order trying to fix it, but then I got it working. After some testing, I figured out that grub only works properly when I go into the bios first. That means that every time that I want turn on or restart my computer, I need to go into the bios, and then save and exit (without actually making any changes).

This has been working ok without any issues, but it still is annoying and ruins my experience using Ubuntu. I've looked around a lot trying to find it happening to anyone else, but I haven't found anyone with the same problem.

I tried repairing grub a while ago, but after doing that it still didn't work (but now there are a lot more options in grub).

My computer specs are:

- Ryzen 5 1600
- Gigabyte AB350N Gaming wifi
- RX580 8GB
- (I assume that things like memory, PSU, etc. aren't relevant)

I have Windows installed on a 250 GB 2.5 inch Sata SSD and Ubuntu installed on an m.2 SSD.

**Edit:** After looking through my bios settings to find something I could change to fix it, I tried disabling "fast boot", which I had enabled for Windows, before I started using Ubuntu. I only vaguely know why it fixed it (I think it's only meant to be used for Windows) and I don't know why it worked at all for a period of time when I started using Linux. If anyone else reads this with the same problem, then I suggest trying to disable fast boot (if you have it enabled).

Comment: Can you change BIOS settings and have them remain changed after a reboot?

Comment: Yeah I can, I've been able to do things like changing the boot order to windows and it's worked.

Comment: With disabled fast boot works!

Comment: Having the exact same problem with a dual boot windows/ubuntu system. After going into Bios and simply choosing Discard Changes and exit, i can see the normal Grub menu to choose OS to boot into. 

But after any restart I get into GRUB prompt on boot if i dont enter BIOS.

Comment: I had this issue and it was solved when I disabled Fast Boot in my bios menu. It turned out that not all drives would be detected by grub when Fast Boot was on and I booted normally. I verified this by running "ls" in the grub cmd with and without going through the bios first and seeing fewer drives when not going through the bios. I think Fast Boot causes the boot process to not wait on all drives to be ready, which did not work well when my Linux install and grub's config was on one of those drives.