# Ubuntu 20.04/Windows 10 Dual Boot "error: file '/efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi' not found" when boot into Windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-10

I have a Tongfang Recoil III laptop with Windows 10 installer on a NVMe SSD and I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 on a second NVMe SSD.

After the first ubuntu configurations and updates, I restart my laptop and tried to boot into windows, and the following error message appeared:

```
error: no such device: ECD8-XXXX

error: file `/efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi' not found

Press any key to continue...
```

After this error I went into the BIOS menu and confirmed the boot order: "ubuntu" and then "Windows Boot Manager".

After exiting the BIOS without any changes made, but saving the changes on exit, the laptop booted into GRUB, I chose Windows 10 again and I was able to boot without any errors.

What I already did:

Checked the BIOS for any fast boot option and it does not have any.

Disabled Windows 10 Fast Boot option

Gave boot-repair a try (update GRUB, reinstall, ...)

Tried adding a custom GRUB menu entry equal to the auto generated one for windows but with the following line before the chainloader:

```
set root='(hd1,gpt2)'
```

After all this attempts to fix the issue, it remains with the same behaviour as described in the beggining.

My main frustration is: why does it boots well into windows when I first go into BIOS, even without changing anything?

Can someone help me? I have already spent hours around this and I don't know what to do anymore...

Comment: look at my answer on this post might help you https://askubuntu.com/a/1309228/1173033

Answer (score 0):

i follow this link:
[Grub only works after viewing bios first](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1077625/grub-only-works-after-viewing-bios-first)

i had exactly the same problem, i disabled "fast boot" in my Bios, and it fixed it ;). For the explication, i'm waiting for much better than me.

Comment: as I said before, I don't have the "Fast Boot" option available in my BIOS menu... I already disabled fast boot in windows but the problem remains...