# Dualboot Ubuntu/Windows: “Error: file '/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi' not found”

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 20.04, uefi, windows-10

Referring to [Same Issue 1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1271907/dualboot-ubuntu-windows-error-file-efi-microsoft-boot-bootmgfw-efi-not-fou) and [Same Issue 2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1281636/ubuntu-20-04-windows-10-dual-boot-error-file-efi-microsoft-boot-bootmgfw-efi) I understood that **Disabling Fast Boot** and **Editing grub.cfg** is not my solution as I checked that.

I using Ubuntu 20.04 along with Windows 10 and was working fine for like a considerable amount of time till Windows wouldn't boot from this issue. I have my [Boot Repair Diagnostics](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/qNTYQHGrZb/) ready. Please let me know if any additional information is needed to diagnose the problem.

EDIT:
My update-grub returns the following:

> Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub' Sourcing file` /etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
> Generating grub configuration file ...
> Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-53-generic
> Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-53-generic
> Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-52-generic
> Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-52-generic
> Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/sda1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
> Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings
> done

Still not fixing the issue.

Comment: You have UEFI installs of Windows & Ubuntu in sda, gpt partitioned. But you have old BIOS boot loaders in MBR of all drives and sdb & sdc are MBR(msdos) partitioned. UEFI & BIOS are not compatible. Can you directly boot Windows from UEFI boot menu. If not you need Windows repairs. But grub only boots working Windows and that also means Windows fast start up must be off. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1288661/windows-10-doesnt-start-after-setting-up-dual-boot-with-ubuntu-20-04/1288764#1288764
http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions

Comment: @oldfred So is there a chance that this got changed after something? It was working perfectly fine for like a month before this happened.

Comment: Windows updates regularly turn fast startup back on which sets hibernation flag. Then grub will not boot Windows. And Windows may update UEFI, which resets some settings back to defaults. Check UEFI settings. I do not have Windows but keep a list of UEFI settings so after an update, I can make sure settings are correct.

Comment: This post might help you, i solved my error(same error) like this.
https://askubuntu.com/a/1309228/1173033